# Value of a complex number based on some equations and inequations

Tags: complex-numbers

$z_{1}$ and $z_{2}$ are complex numbers such that $|z_{1}| \le 1$ and $|z_{2}| \le 1$. Also $|z_{1} + iz_{2}| = |z_{1} - i\bar{z_{2}}| = 2$. Find $z_{1}$.

My attempt: I tried to assume $z_{1} = x_{1} + iy_{1}$ and $z_{2} = x_{2} + iy_{2}$. After simplifying using the equalities, I reached the step $x_{2}y_{1} = 0$. Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Hint: by the triangle inequality both $z_1$ and $z_2$ are on the unit circle, not inside. In fact you can say more about their relative positions, which will give you a constraint for $z_2$ that you can solve and then obtain $z_1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have: $$4=|z_1+iz_2|^2=(z_1+iz_2)(\overline{z_1}-i\overline{z_2})=|z_1^2|-iz_1\overline{z_2}+i\overline{z_1}z_2 + |z_2|^2 \tag{1}$$ $$4=|z_1-i\overline{z_2}|^2=(z_1-i\overline{z_2})(\overline{z_1}+iz_2)=|z_1^2|+iz_1z_2-i\overline{z_1}\overline{z_2}+|z_2^2| \tag{2}$$
Subtracting the two equations, we get, $$iz_1[z_2+\overline{z_2}]-i\overline{z_1}[z_2+\overline{z_2}] =0 \implies [z_1-\overline{z_1}][z_2+\overline{z_2}]=0$$

If $z_1-\overline{z_1}=0$, then because, $1=z_1\overline{z_1} \implies z_1= 1 \text{ or } -1\tag{3}$

If $z_2+\overline{z_2}=0$, then because $\Re(z_2)=0\implies |z_2|=1 \implies z_2=i\tag{4}$

Then, Eq. $(1)$ becomes: $$4=|z_1-1|^2 \implies |z_1^2|-z_1-\overline{z_1}+1=4 \implies z_1+\overline{z_1}=-2 \implies z_1=-1\tag{5}$$

What can you conclude from $(3)$ and $(5)$?

Answer (score 0):

$\overline{iz_2}=-i\overline{z_2}$ then $|z_{1} + iz_{2}| = |z_{1} - i\bar{z_{2}}|$ shows $z_1$ lies on bisection of $iz_2$ and $\overline{iz_2}$, that is on real line. The triangular $z_1$, $iz_2$ and $\overline{iz_2}$ is isoscelestriangle with sides $2$ and since $|z_1|\leq1$ and $|z_2|\leq1$, this is impossible, unless $iz_2$ is a real number also, then $z_1=x\pm2$ and $iz_2=x$ implies $|x\pm2|\leq1$ and $|x|\leq1$, mean $x=-1$ only.

Comment: The given inequalities are nonstrict.

Comment: @Ian Thanks....

Comment: This means that your "impossible" statement is wrong...the relevant "triangle" is in fact a line segment.